# Map numbers to their percentiles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, percentile

I would like to *apply* the *result* of [`numpy.percentile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) to its argument, i.e., map every number in the input vector to its quantile.

E.g., if `v=np.array([1,2,3,4])`, and I want just two quantiles (bigger and smaller than the median), I would get `np.array([0,0,1,1])` telling me that the first two elements of `v` are smaller than the median and the last two are bigger than the median.

Note that I am interested in, say, deciles, not just the median!

IOW, @PaulPanzer hit the nail:

```
np.digitize(v,np.percentile(v,quantiles))
```

thanks!

Comment: have a look at `numpy.digitize`

Comment: @PaulPanzer: please turn your comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.digitize`:

```
perc = np.percentile(data, q)
indices = np.digitize(data, perc)
```

Example `q = [25,50,75]`, `data = np.arange(8)`:

```
indices
# array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(v > np.percentile(v, 50)).astype(int)
Out[93]:
array([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Comment: what do I do for, say 10 percentiles, not just the median?

Comment: Looks like you get the answer. I was about to suggest something like `np.digitize(v, bins = np.percentile(v, np.arange(10, 100, 10)))`.